# Configuring sendTimeout in connecting to ActiveMQ with Jboss resource adapter

Tags: jboss, jms, activemq-classic, jboss6.x

Based on this [link](http://rastkososkic.blogspot.de/2013/12/deploying-activemq-590-resource-adapter.html?showComment=1422559659598#c2672386122249314801), i've connected `JBoss eap 6.2` to an external `ActiveMQ 5.9.0`. The `org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory` has a `sendTimeout` field that i want to set. But in this approach i can't access to this class directly and it seems all i can do is adding some parameter to `ServerUrl` in `resouce-adapter` deceleration in `standalone.xml` in JBoss.

Based on this [link](http://activemq.apache.org/tcp-transport-reference.html), it's possible to add some parameter to `ServerUrl`, but it seems it hasn't `sendTimeout` parameter. And this [link](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/configuring.html) (ActiveMQ CPP) introduces some other parameters, that they don't work and I get below error in Jboss startup:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid connect parameters: {connection.sendTimeout=20000}
```

ActiveMQ `resource-adapter` in `standalone.xml` file:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">
    <resource-adapters>
        <resource-adapter id="activemq-rar.ra">
            <module slot="main" id="org.apache.activemq"/>
            <transaction-support>LocalTransaction</transaction-support>
            <config-property name="ServerUrl">tcp://localhost:61616?connection.sendTimeout=20000</config-property>
            <connection-definitions>
                <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/activemq/ConnectionFactory" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ActiveMQConnectionFactoryPool">
                </connection-definition>
            </connection-definitions>
        </resource-adapter>
        <!--resource-adapter-->
    </resource-adapters>
</subsystem>
```

So how can i set value of this parameter? Should i config `ServerUrl` in `ra.xml` file instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this config page](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/configuring.html), `timeout` parameter of `Failover Transport Options`:

> If a send is blocked waiting on a failed connection to reconnect how
>   long should it wait before failing the send, default is forever (-1).

So I've changed `ServerUrl` property of `resource-adapter` and `ra.xml` to:

> failover://(tcp://127.0.0.1:61616)?timeout=20000